# Как тестировать хранимые процедуры?

Tags: sql-server

Как проще всего тестировать хранимые процедуры? Желательно без лишнего софта.

Comment: @Alex9, я подозреваю, что только руками из консоли. SQL все-таки не язык программирования, и там по умолчанию куда больше завязанности на реальную струкутуру и реальные таблицы, поэтому модульное тестирование вряд ли вообще можно организовать.

Comment: А тестировать - это вообще про что? Сервер сделает так, как ему скажут, а то, что кто-то имел в виду другое - это не его проблемы.

Comment: >А тестировать - это вообще про что? Сервер сделает так, как ему скажут, а то, что кто-то имел в виду другое - это не его проблемы

ну по этой логике тестировать вообще не нужно - любая программа выполнит то, что ей скажут, а остальное - не ее проблемы

Comment: @maxleo https://github.com/etki/yii-testing-playground/blob/master/guide/ru/04-testing-basics.md ну и там в соседних файлах много чего, но ничего не дописано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, написать SQL-скрипт со следующими шагами:

1. Подготовка исходных (например, заполнение таблицы, данные из которой используются в процедуре).
2. Вызов процедуры с нужными параметрами.
3. Проверка результатов работы процедуры. Если данные не сошлись -- выбрасывать ошибку.
4. Вне зависимости от результатов теста, очистка таблиц после себя.

Как вариант, можно в начале и конце добавить создание и удаление всей БД. Плюс написать некоторый bat-файл, который будет запускать все ваши тестовые сценарии и выводить результат.

Но вообще я бы посоветовал пользоваться специализированными тулами, они ведь для этого и созданы: [Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj851203(v=vs.103).aspx) (да, внезапно), [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net), [tSQLt](http://tsqlt.org).